# Firebase Rules Write Permissions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to firebase, so apologies if this is a dumb question. Firebase keeps sending me emails with the statement below:

> We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
>
> - any user can read your entire database
> - any logged-in user can write to your entire database

My app is a charades game, and does not ask for user login (there is no user input whatsoever) so I cannot use the userID rules that I've seen as a recommendation from similar questions posted here.

I don't mind anyone being able to read my database, however, I would like to set a permission such that I'm the only one with write access to the database.

Given that I cannot use a userID permission, how can I change my database settings such that I'm the only one able to write to it?

Comment: Given that you apparently don't use sign-in, how do you identify the "I" in "such that I'm the only one with write access to the database"?

Answer (score 1):

If you only set data from your own development machine, consider using the Admin SDK. This SDK accesses the backend with administrative permissions, so it bypasses security rules. This means you can have these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

---

The typical first step I do when I create an application admin page (usually a simple StackBlitz or JSBin), even before signing in the users anonymously, is to sign myself in anonymously, log my UID, and then only give write permissions to my UID.

In rules that'd look something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'myUid'"
  }
}
```

---

Later if I expand the user sign-in (even if again only for fellow administrators), I expand this to a more elaborate check, such as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'myUid' || 
               (auth.token.email_verified == true && 
                auth.token.email.matches(/.*@google.com$/))"
  }
}
```

---

With all of the above rules, you'll still get a warning about the user's ability to read your entire database though. The main problem with the top-level `".read": true` is that it allows crawling your website with a single HTTP GET to `https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/.json`. There are quite some scripts out there that use this to find user information

If this is **not** a concern for your app, you can disable the alerts at this point.

If it **is** a concern, you can consider protecting the data by encoding the access patterns in your rules.

For example, if you have one top-level node that contains a list of all games, and then another top-level node that then contains the move for each game, you might push the read-permissions down to those levels:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "games": {
      ".read": true,
    },
    "moves": {
      "$gameid": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This this structure, anyone can read the full list of games. But one can only read the moves for a single game at the time. This matches with an application where you first see a list of games, and then see the move for a game that you select.

With these rules the user still has access to all data, but only if they follow the rules of your application. And (maybe more importantly) the blatant top-level `https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/.json` access won't work anymore.